# Can you have a one to many relationship with 3 tables?

Tags: sql

Working on a hobby project, have 0 database design experience, and trying to wrap my head around how to model the following.

I have an appointments, users, and tutors table.

Each appointment will have 1 user and 1 tutor.

In this situation can I use a one-to-many relationship where I link one appointment to one user and one tutor.

Or does it make more sense to make the appointment table the many-to-many third table, which takes a user and a tutor?

I feel like it should probably be many-to-many, but a second opinion would be great based on my lack of experiance

Comment: Can you include either an ERD or table structure to clarify what it is you are asking?

Comment: Are you asking if you need appointments, users, tutors *and* a fourth join table? No, just three. Appointments is the join table.

Comment: The appointment table has FKs to users and tutors